# How to search a png image from a summary and remove it using regex in python?

Tags: python

I have a summary which is a paragraph with various updates. I wanted to search for all the png images and remove it from my summary.

- The regex which I am writing is missing a case when there is width and height in the image for example  !image-2020-05-07-06-52-37-619.png|width=550,height=327! whereas this !image-2021-06-07-06-51-01-023.png! is getting matched and removed.

Below is my code, can someone help to finetune my regex in order to catch this?

```
image = re.findall(r'!image(.*?).png!', summary)
if image:
    for img in image:
        image_line = "!image" + img + ".png!"
        summary = summary.split(image_line)
        summary = "".join(summary)
```

Comment: if you want to remove the characters use re.subs.

Comment: If you update your question to include a sample synopsis I will debug it completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the regex does not match the text between the *"png"* and the *"!"* so the match is being ignored.

**If we consider the regex in detail we can see where the problem:**
[image: regex problem]

**The solution is to update the regex to match after the png as well as before:**
[image: regex solution]

Another minor fix is rather than using `re.split` to cut out all images then join them back together it is possible just use `re.sub` to replace the text with the *empty string*, which is the same as removing them.

With these changes your code will look like this:

```
import re

synopsis = 'The regex which I am writing is missing a case when there is width and height in the image for example !image-2020-05-07-06-52-37-619.png|width=550,height=327! whereas this !image-2020-05-07-06-52-37-619.png|width=550,height=327!'

pattern = r'!.*?png.*?!'  # This pattern matches both characters before and after png inside the !

replacement = ''  # we replace with nothing to make the image text disappear

result = re.sub(pattern, replacement, synopsis) # We can substitute method to replace the image text with no text

print(result)
```

[Online running version](https://www.online-python.com/FJrU0Ly9Sp)

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you for the elaborated and accurate answer. Got to learn something new today :)